# use bloginfo('template_directory') in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to give my wordpress dashboard custom css styles by using external css file in my theme. This is my code:

```
<?php
// Custom Dashboard Styles by Loading assets/css/admin.css
function filmview_admin_css() {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="bloginfo('template_directory')/assets/css/admin.css" type="text/css" media="all" />';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'filmview_admin_css');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `bloginfo()` and `echo` at the same time because `bloginfo()` is already outputting a string.

Anyway, I suggest you to use `get_template_directory_uri()`, `get_theme_file_uri()` or `get_parent_theme_file_uri()` instead because those functions are meant to be used on `functions.php` for this kind of purposes.

Also, to enqueue styles or scripts, you should use WordPress built in functions like [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) and hooks like [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts/):

```
function filmview_admin_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/admin.css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'filmview_admin_css' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this thread https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41207/how-do-i-enqueue-styles-scripts-on-certain-wp-admin-pages.

In general you could use:

`function admin_custom_css() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet_name', 'stylesheet.css');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'admin_custom_css' );`

Don't hardcode things like `<link rel="...` as it is bad practice and WordPress can do it all for you in a coherent way.